# How do two routers (from two different entities) talk to each other?

Tags: routing, switching

Let's say there are two routers and they are neighbors, but administered by two different organizations/entities, running two different routing protocols. How are they able talk to each other?

Comment: The Internet is a collection of interconnected component networks that share a common addressing structure, a common view of routing, and a common view of a naming system. This interconnection environment spans many component networks. Therefore, every ISP must not only coexist with other ISPs but also must operate in cooperation with other ISPs. Underneath the competitive retail environment is a an environment, in which every internet network must interoperate with neighboring Internet networks in order to produce an outcome.

Comment: Therefore, different entities or organizations need to negotiate a routing protocol suitable for both parties, hence the possibility to interconnect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routing protocols don't transport user data, routing protocols exchange information about routes. A route tells a router through which of its interfaces and neighbor routers a certain destination network can be reached.

User data is transported in packets and these are routed over multiple hops from source to destination. Each hop/router makes a forwarding decision based on the routes it knows about.

Routers that are supposed to talk to each other need a common connection. This can be a direct 1:1 physical link, a tunnel, or a network (often Ethernet) they are both connected to (like a common link segment at an Internet exchange).

If neighbor routers are to exchange routing information (ie. they exchange knowledge about routes to networks they know about) they need a common routing protocol. With different routing protocols they can't exchange routes and don't learn from each other. Of course, routes can also be configured in a static fashion but with a growing number of routes this becomes less practical.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationship between the entities.

For an end site with a single IP using NAT it is likely that the provider will simply treat the customers router as-if it was an end device. The provider will allocate the customer their IP either using DHCP or using the IP allocation features in PPP. The customers router in turn will point it's default route at the provider and will perform NAT to hide the private IPs of the internal devices behind the single public IP.

For an end site with a single block of public IPs and a single upstream provider it is most likely that static configurations will be used. The provider will tell the customer what settings to use on the external-facing port of their router and will then statically route the customer's IP block to the customer's external address. The customer will point their default route at the provider's router.

For complex relationships where large numbers of prefixes need to be exchanged between the entities BGP is normally used to exchange prefixes.